# how to use spark intersection() by key or filter() with two RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd, intersection

I want to use `intersection()` by key or `filter()` in spark.

But I really don't know how to use `intersection()` by key.

So I tried to use `filter()`, but it's not worked.

example - here is two RDD:

```
data1 //RDD[(String, Int)] = Array(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1))
data2 //RDD[(String, Int)] = Array(("a", 3), ("b", 5))

val data3 = data2.map{_._1}

data1.filter{_._1 == data3}.collect //Array[(String, Int] = Array()
```

I want to get a (key, value) pair with the same key as `data1` based on the key that `data2` has.

`Array(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3))` is the result I want.

Is there a method to solve this problem using `intersection()` by key or `filter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## This can be achieved in different ways

### 1. `broadcast` variable in `filter()` - needs scalability improvement

```
val data1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
val data2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 3), ("b", 5)))

// broadcast data2 key list to use in filter method, which runs in executor nodes
val bcast = sc.broadcast(data2.map(_._1).collect())

val result = data1.filter(r => bcast.value.contains(r._1))


println(result.collect().toList)
//Output
List((a,1), (a,2), (b,2), (b,3))
```

### 2. `cogroup` (similar to group by key)

```
val data1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
val data2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 3), ("b", 5)))

val cogroupRdd: RDD[(String, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))] = data1.cogroup(data2)
/* List(
  (a, (CompactBuffer(1, 2), CompactBuffer(3))),
  (b, (CompactBuffer(2, 3), CompactBuffer(5))),
  (c, (CompactBuffer(1), CompactBuffer()))
) */

//Now filter keys which have two non empty CompactBuffer. You can do that with 
//filter(row => row._2._1.nonEmpty && row._2._2.nonEmpty) also. 
val filterRdd = cogroupRdd.filter { case (k, (v1, v2)) => v1.nonEmpty && v2.nonEmpty } 
/* List(
  (a, (CompactBuffer(1, 2), CompactBuffer(3))),
  (b, (CompactBuffer(2, 3), CompactBuffer(5)))
) */

//As we care about first data only, lets pick first compact buffer only 
// by doing v1.map(val1 => (k, val1))
val result = filterRdd.flatMap { case (k, (v1, v2)) => v1.map(val1 => (k, val1)) }
//List((a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 2), (b, 3))
```

### 3. Using inner join

```
val resultRdd = data1.join(data2).map(r => (r._1, r._2._1)).distinct()
//List((b,2), (b,3), (a,2), (a,1))
```

Here `data1.join(data2)` holds pairs with common keys (**inner join**)

```
//List((a,(1,3)), (a,(2,3)), (b,(2,5)), (b,(2,1)), (b,(3,5)), (b,(3,1)))
```

Answer (score 6):

For your problem, I think `cogroup()` is better suited. The `intersection()` method will consider both keys and values in your data, and will result in an empty `rdd`.

The function `cogroup()` groups the values of both `rdd`'s by key and gives us `(key, vals1, vals2)`, where `vals1` and `vals2` contain the values of `data1` and `data2` respectively, for each key. Note that if a certain key is not shared in both datasets, one of `vals1` or `vals2` will be returned as an empty `Seq`, hence we'll first have to filter out these tuples to arrive at the *intersection* of the two `rdd`'s.

Next, we'll grab `vals1` - which contains *the values* from `data1` for the common *keys* - and convert it to format `(key, Array)`. Lastly we use `flatMapValues()` to unpack the result into the format of `(key, value)`.

```
val result = (data1.cogroup(data2)
  .filter{case (k, (vals1, vals2)) => vals1.nonEmpty && vals2.nonEmpty }
  .map{case (k, (vals1, vals2)) => (k, vals1.toArray)}
  .flatMapValues(identity[Array[Int]]))

result.collect()
// Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (a,2), (b,2), (b,3))
```

Comment: I don't understand `cogroup` well, what if I want to use functional operation like `val result = data1.filter(r => bcast.value.contains(myFuncOper(r._1)))` in `cogroup`?