# Spark filter one RDD by keys in another RDD

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

Here is two RDD:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(("a","b"))
rdd2 = sc.parallelize((("a", 3), ("b", 5), ("c",4)))
```

I want to filter rdd2 with keys in data1. The result should be

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 5)]
```

If the sizes of RDDs are small, I can collect and broadcast rdd1, and then use a filter transformation to get the result.
However, the size of rdd1 is large. So the method I'm now using is the join function:

```
rdd1.map(lambda x : (x,1)).join(rdd2).mapValues(lambda x : x[1])
```

Since the cost of join increases with the size of data, is there a better to achieve the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use spark intersection() by key or filter() with two RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325496/how-to-use-spark-intersection-by-key-or-filter-with-two-rdd)

Comment: can you convert to dataframe ??

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I'm not quite familiar with spark DataFrame. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: @mtoto Yes, I found that question. The answer used the broadcast variable or the join operation. I wonder if there is a better choice since it is, in fact, a filter operation.

Comment: A [`cogroup`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) may be more appropriate than a `join`

Comment: @Federico any difference between `join` and `cogroup` ?

Comment: @cssmlulu  `join` uses `cogroup` internally (see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala)), and I think that for your use case the `cogroup` (faster) is enough. After the `cogroup`, with a `mapPartitions` you can convert each pair of interators to sets, perform an intersection and return an iterator of the result.